# How to replace .. in a string in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace this string to become this

```
import re 

s = "haha..hehe.hoho"
s = re.sub('[..+]+',' ', s)
```

my output i get `haha hehe hoho`

**desired output**

```
haha hehe.hoho
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Must you use a regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test on sites like regexpal: http://regexpal.com/
It's easier to get the output and check if the regex is right.

You should change your regex to something like: '\.\.' if you want to remove only double dots.
If you want to remove when there's at least 2 dots you can use '\.{2,}'.

Every character you put inside a [] will be checked against your expression
And the dot character has a special meaning on a regex, to avoid this meaning you should prefix it with a escape character: \

You can read more about regular expressions metacharacters here: https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php

> [a-z] A range of characters. Matches any character in the specified
>   range.
>
> . Matches any single character except "n".
>
> \ Specifies the next character as either a special character, a literal, a back reference, or an octal escape.

Your new code:

```
import re 

s = "haha..hehe.hoho"
#pattern = '\.\.' #If you want to remove when there's 2 dots
pattern = '\.{2,}' #If you want to remove when there's at least 2 dots
s = re.sub(pattern, ' ', s)
```

Comment: `s = re.sub(pattern, s)` causes `TypeError: sub() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)`

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks to point it, I accidentally removed the ' ' argument when editing, fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are constrained to use regex, then I find the `replace()` function much simpler:

```
s = "haha..hehe.hoho"
print s.replace('..',' ')
```

gives your desired output:

```
haha hehe.hoho
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
re.sub('[..+]+',' ', s)
```

to:

```
re.sub('\.\.+',' ', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

`[..+]+` , this meaning in `regex` is that use the any in the list at least one time. So it matches the `..` as well as `.` in your input. Make the changes as below:

```
s = re.sub('\.\.+',' ', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what your regex means:

[image]

So, you allow for 1 or more literal periods or plus symbols, which is not the case.

You do not have to repeat the same symbol when looking for it, you can use quantifiers, like `{2}`, which means "exactly 2 occurrences".

You can use `split` and `join`, see [sample working program](http://goo.gl/pwtRjM):

```
import re 

s = "haha..hehe.hoho"
s = " ".join(re.split(r'\.{2}', s))
print s
```

Output:

```
haha hehe.hoho
```

Or you can use the `sub` with the regex, too:

```
s = re.sub(r'\.{2}', ' ', "haha..hehe.hoho")
```

In case you have cases  with more than 2 periods, you should use `\.{2,}` regex.

Comment: your output is completely different from desired output.

Comment: Now, it yields expected results.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is a character class and will match on anything in it (meaning any 1 `.`).

I'm guessing you used it because a simple `.` wouldn't work, because it's a meta character meaning any character. You can simply escape it to mean a literal dot with a `\`. As such:

```
s = re.sub('\.\.',' ', s)
```